# Ошибка при вызове метода remove()

Tags: python, pygame

Мой код :

```py
import os
import sys
import random
import pygame
 
 

class Player(object):
    
    def __init__(self):
        self.rect = pygame.Rect(32, 32, 16, 16)
    def move(self, dx, dy):
        if dx != 0:
            self.move_single_axis(dx, 0)
        if dy != 0:
            self.move_single_axis(0, dy)
    def move_single_axis(self, dx, dy):
        self.rect.x += dx
        self.rect.y += dy
        
        for wall in walls:
            if self.rect.colliderect(wall.rect):
                if dx > 0: 
                    self.rect.right = wall.rect.left
                if dx < 0: 
                    self.rect.left = wall.rect.right
                if dy > 0: 
                    self.rect.bottom = wall.rect.top
                if dy < 0: 
                    self.rect.top = wall.rect.bottom
        for coin in coins:
            if self.rect.colliderect(coin.rect):
                if dx > 0: 
                    self.rect.right = coin.rect.left
                if dx < 0: 
                    self.rect.left = coin.rect.right
                if dy > 0: 
                    self.rect.bottom = coin.rect.top
                if dy < 0: 
                    self.rect.top = coin.rect.bottom
 

class Wall(object):
    
    def __init__(self, pos):
        walls.append(self)
        self.rect = pygame.Rect(pos[0], pos[1], 16, 16)
class coin(object):
    
    def __init__(self, pos):
        coins.append(self)
        self.rect = pygame.Rect(pos[0], pos[1], 16, 16)


os.environ["SDL_VIDEO_CENTERED"] = "1"
pygame.init()
 

pygame.display.set_caption("Get to the red square!")
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((320, 240))
 
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
walls = []
coins = []
player = Player() 
 

level = [
    "WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWW",
    "W                 OW",
    "W   w    WWWWWW    W",
    "W   WWWW       W   W",
    "W   W        WWWW  W",
    "WWWWW  WWWW        W",
    "WO  W     W W    O W",
    "W   W   O W   WWW WW",
    "W   WWW WWW   WOW  W",
    "W     W   W   W W  W",
    "WWW   W   WWWWW W  W",
    "W W      WW        W",
    "W W   WWWW   WWW   W",
    "W     W    E   W   W",
    "WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWW",
]
 

x = y = 0
for row in level:
    for col in row:
        if col == "W":
            Wall((x, y))
        if col == "E":
            end_rect = pygame.Rect(x, y, 16, 16)
        if col == "O":
            coin= pygame.Rect(x, y, 16, 16)
        x += 16
    y += 16
    x = 0
 
running = True
while running:
    
    clock.tick(60)
    
    for e in pygame.event.get():
        if e.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False
        if e.type == pygame.KEYDOWN and e.key == pygame.K_ESCAPE:
            running = False
 
    
    key = pygame.key.get_pressed()
    if key[pygame.K_LEFT]:
        player.move(-2, 0)
    if key[pygame.K_RIGHT]:
        player.move(2, 0)
    if key[pygame.K_UP]:
        player.move(0, -2)
    if key[pygame.K_DOWN]:
        player.move(0, 2)
 
    
    if player.rect.colliderect(end_rect):
        pygame.quit()
        sys.exit()
    score_value=0
    font = pygame.font.Font(None,20)
    textx=15
    texty=15
    def show_score(x,y):
        score = font.render('счёт:' + str(score_value),True,(200,200,200))
        screen.blit(score,(x,y))
    if player.rect.colliderect(coin):
        row.remove(coin)
        sc+=1

    
    
    
    screen.fill((0, 0, 0))
    for wall in walls:
        pygame.draw.rect(screen, (255, 255, 255), wall.rect)
    pygame.draw.rect(screen, (255, 0, 0), end_rect)
    pygame.draw.rect(screen, (255, 200, 0), player.rect)
    pygame.draw.rect(screen, (255, 100, 0), coin)
    show_score(textx,texty)
    pygame.display.flip()
    clock.tick(360)
 
pygame.quit()
```

ошибка, когда игрок дотрагивается до монетки (оранжевого квадрата):

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Asus\Desktop\111111.py", line 134, in <module>
    row.remove(coin)
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'remove'
```

Comment: Ну так английским по белому написано, "в строке 134  используется оператор row.remove(coin), этот объект имеет тип 'str' и (соответственно) не имеет атрибута 'remove'. Что тут непонятного?

Answer (score 1):

Все просто объект, с типом данных строка не имеет метода `remove()`. Для удаленеия объектов или замены есть такой метод как `replace()`

На примере:

```py
>>> s = "W   W   O W   WWW WW"
>>> s.replace("O", " ") 
'W   W     W   WWW WW'
```

Буквально заменить "O" на пробельный символ.

Если необходимо удалить из строки, то используйте такое выражение

```py
s.replace("O", "")
```

Только, поскольку строка - это *не изменяемый* тип данных, то при замене создается новый объект строки, в которой заменены символы указаные в параметрах. Данное поведение необходимо учитывать в вашей логике.

То есть если я сейчас спрошу, что содержит перемнная `s`, мы не увидим изменений

```py
print(s)
'W   W   O W   WWW WW'
```

Для того, чтобы изменения применились необходимо явно присваивать

```py
s = s.replace("O", " ")
```

Может быть в вашем случае лучше применить изменяемый тип данных, может быть `list`?